# Flowbite-Svelte: Set height of image

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit, flowbite

```
<script>
  import { Img } from 'flowbite-svelte';
</script>

<Img src={image_url} alt="Listing" class="rounded-lg"/>
```

How do I define the height of the image? I have tried `<Img src={image_url} alt="Listing" size="h-10" class="rounded-lg"/>` but it had no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [docs](https://flowbite-svelte.com/typography/image#Props), you can use `imgClass` to add styles to Image.

> imgClass="h-auto"

```
<Img src={image_url} alt="Listing" class="rounded-lg" imgClass="h-10"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `class` attribute :
`<Img src={image_url} alt="Listing" class="rounded-lg h-10" />`